# how to convert string to date object in ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I am getting a date as a string like below:

```
"September 1998"
```

I tried like `Date.parse("September 1998")`, but it did not work.

How do I convert it into a ruby date object which returns string in above format?

Comment: But "September 1998" is not a date, it is missing the day.

Comment: yes. But I am getting like this only. So is there any way I can convert it to 09-1998

Comment: Aways specify a format when parsing dates, most especially if you're using  formats that might include day and month. Enforce the format based on the user's locale and be sure dates are disambiguated just in case.

Answer (score 9):

`Date.strptime('September 1998', '%B %Y')`. However, this will represent September *1st* 1998, because date objects represent, well, dates.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic):

```
require 'chronic'

t = Chronic.parse('September 1998', :guess => true) #returns a Time object
=> 1998-09-01 00:00:00 -0700

t.to_date #convert to Date object
=> <Date: 1998-09-16 ((2451073j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Chronic was created by [Tom Preston-Werner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Preston-Werner), who also co-created Github.

Answer (score 2):

Just prepend the missing "1 ":

```
str ="September 1998"
p Date.parse("1 " + str) # => #<Date: 1998-09-01 ((2451058j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```